Beamer renders equations differently
I'm making slides using beamer. I noticed that it renders math differently than usual articles. Here is my minimally working example, you can see that the space in the right brackets are smaller in beamer, especially obvious in places like <i, j> and <<i, j>>>, which look very weird:
Beamer:

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
    H &=  -t \sum_{\left< i,j \right>}
    \left( c_i^\dagger c_j + c_j^\dagger c_i  \right)
    - \mu \left( \sum_i n_i - N \right) \\
    &\quad + V_1  \sum_{\left< i,j \right>} (n_i -1) (n_j -1)
    + V_2  \sum_{\left<\hspace{-1.5pt}\left< i,j \right>\hspace{-1.5pt}\right>} (n_i -1) (n_j -1)
\end{align*}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}

Article:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    H &=  -t \sum_{\left< i,j \right>}
    \left( c_i^\dagger c_j + c_j^\dagger c_i  \right)
    - \mu \left( \sum_i n_i - N \right) \\
    &\quad + V_1  \sum_{\left< i,j \right>} (n_i -1) (n_j -1)
    + V_2  \sum_{\left<\hspace{-1.5pt}\left< i,j \right>\hspace{-1.5pt}\right>} (n_i -1) (n_j -1)
\end{align*}
\end{document} 

Why is that, and is there a way to solve this other than manually adding some space? Thanks!

If I test your beamer example, I get more space between j and > : https://i.sstatic.net/XIEx4NAc.png Can you show your .log file?

Are you by chance compiling with xelatex? That's the only engine in which I can reproduce your images. Then I suggest to switch to another engine. Xelatex causes several problems in beamer and more general in latex: https://www.texdev.net/2024/11/05/engine-news-from-the-latex-project

I think this answers applies here as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730301/36296

Yes, I was using XeLaTeX (because I typeset in Chinese occasionally), never thought about that may be causing the problem.

If you need an unicode-aware engine, use lualatex instead.

I see no sensible difference. In order to do the comparison, I produced the “article” version as a standalone document and then included the generated PDF in the beamer frame below the align* environment.

The most striking difference is that the beamer version uses larger fonts. This might be a reason why you find the spacing between the consecutive angle brackets to be too small in the beamer case.
If you use XeLaTeX, don't.
An absolute -1.5pt spacing is not the best and \! should be preferred, which adds a negative space of 3mu, which is 1/6th of an em and is relative to the main font size.
\begin{align*}
    H &=  -t \sum_{\langle i,j \rangle}
    ( c_i^\dagger c_j + c_j^\dagger c_i  )
    - \mu \Bigl( \sum_i n_i - N \Bigr) \\
    &\quad + V_1  \sum_{\langle i,j \rangle} (n_i -1) (n_j -1)
    + V_2  \sum_{\llangle i,j \rrangle} (n_i -1) (n_j -1)
\end{align*}

Note no \left and \right that make the parentheses too big (or have no real effect other than adding unwanted space).
The output shows again the beamer version above the article one.


Compile with xelatex to reproduce the spacing.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It didn't occur to me to use XeLaTeX that way, because it's wrong to begin with.

I agree, xelatex isn't suitable for beamer documents.
